# Ansible iterate from a list

Tags: ansible, yaml, devops

I'm trying to parse a json output (added below) and add it into a new JSON file to save the variables

The values that i need are **metadata.name** and **metadata.namespace**.

The following JSON is the file that i need to parse and extract the values. I get this output from the command: `kubectl get pod -o json.`

```
{
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "items": [
    {
      "apiVersion": "v1",
      "kind": "Pod",
      "metadata": {
        "creationTimestamp": "2022-12-21T12:18:49Z",
        "generateName": "backend-99fb66465-",
        "labels": {
          "app": "backend",
          "pod-template-hash": "99fb66465"
        },
        "name": "backend-99fb66465-2lxwp",
        "namespace": "testingspace",

    },
    {
      "apiVersion": "v1",
      "kind": "Pod",
      "metadata": {
        "creationTimestamp": "2022-12-21T12:18:49Z",
        "generateName": "backend-99fb66465-",
        "labels": {
          "app": "backend",
          "pod-template-hash": "99fb66465"
        },
        "name": "backend-99fb66465-2lxwp",
        "namespace": "testingspace",

    }
]
[...]
}
```

My ansible code is this one:

```
- name: Search for all running pods from file ./data/kubernetes/pods-status
  shell: | 
    cat ./data/kubernetes/pods-status
  register: pods
    
- name: Pods name
  set_fact:
    podnames: "{{ pods.stdout|from_json|json_query(names) }}"
    podkind: "{{ pods.stdout|from_json|json_query(kind) }}"
  vars:
    names: 'items[*].metadata.name'
    kind: 'items[*].kind'

- name: Copy pods information to local file
  local_action: 
  module: copy
    dest: "./data/kubernetes/mainpod.json"
    #content: "{{ podsjson | to_json }} "
    content: "{{ [{'val': item }] }}"
  loop: "{{  podnames }}"
```

I'm expecting to have the following file:

```
{
  "items": {
    "name": "backend-99fb66465-2lxwp",
    "namespace":"testingspace" 
    },
    {
    "name": "backend-99fb66465-2lxwp",
    "namespace": "testingspace"
    }
  }
}
```

But so far i just have this one:

```
[{"val": "backup-mysqldump-27875520-d26j4"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the data in the dictionary for testing

```yaml
  pods:
    apiVersion: v1
    items:
    - apiVersion: v1
      kind: Pod
      metadata:
        creationTimestamp: '2022-12-21T12:18:49Z'
        generateName: backend-99fb66465-
        labels:
          app: backend
          pod-template-hash: 99fb66465
        name: backend-99fb66465-2lxwp
        namespace: testingspace
    - apiVersion: v1
      kind: Pod
      metadata:
        creationTimestamp: '2022-12-21T12:18:49Z'
        generateName: backend-99fb66465-
        labels:
          app: backend
          pod-template-hash: 99fb66465
        name: backend-99fb66465-2lxwp
        namespace: testingspace
```

---

Declare the query

```yaml
  name_space: "{{ pods|json_query(name_space_query) }}"
  name_space_query: 'items[].{name: metadata.name,
                              namespace: metadata.namespace}'
```

gives

```yaml
  name_space:
  - name: backend-99fb66465-2lxwp
    namespace: testingspace
  - name: backend-99fb66465-2lxwp
    namespace: testingspace
```

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    pods:
      apiVersion: v1
      items:
      - apiVersion: v1
        kind: Pod
        metadata:
          creationTimestamp: '2022-12-21T12:18:49Z'
          generateName: backend-99fb66465-
          labels:
            app: backend
            pod-template-hash: 99fb66465
          name: backend-99fb66465-2lxwp
          namespace: testingspace
      - apiVersion: v1
        kind: Pod
        metadata:
          creationTimestamp: '2022-12-21T12:18:49Z'
          generateName: backend-99fb66465-
          labels:
            app: backend
            pod-template-hash: 99fb66465
          name: backend-99fb66465-2lxwp
          namespace: testingspace

    name_space: "{{ pods|json_query(name_space_query) }}"
    name_space_query: 'items[].{name: metadata.name,
                                namespace: metadata.namespace}'

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: name_space
```